Inequality about diagonal elements of matrix (Potential intermediate step of Boyd & Vandenberghe exercise 5.36)
Consider $U \in S^m$,  $V \in S^n$, $X\in R^{m\times n}$ ($m \geq n$), and $k\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ ($k$'s domain may not be strictly necessary).
How to derive
$$
|X_{ii}| \leq 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_{ii}| \leq k
$$
from
$$
\begin{bmatrix} U & X \\ X^T & V \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
U - I \preceq 0 \\
V - I \preceq 0 \\
\text{Tr} U + \text{Tr} V = 2k
$$
I guess this may be related to Schur complement and certain trace inequalities, but could not progress.
This is my intermediate step when solving Boyd & Vandenberghe exercise 5.36 about the sum of the largest k singular values of a matrix. I guess these inequalities with X diagonals should hold empirically, which leads to the proof of 5.36(a). If my guess is wrong, please also specify.

As the block matrix is positive semidefinite, so are $U$ and $V$. Therefore $u_{ii},v_{jj}\ge0$ for all $i$ and $j$.
Since $U,V\preceq I$, we also have $u_{ii},v_{jj}\le1$. It follows that $u_{ii},v_{jj}\in[0,1]$.
As the block matrix is positive semidefinite, so are its $2\times2$ principal submatrices. In particular, $\pmatrix{u_{ii}&x_{ij}\\ x_{ij}&v_{jj}}\succeq0$. Therefore the corresponding minor is nonnegative, i.e., $x_{ij}^2\le u_{ii}v_{jj}$. In turn, $|x_{ij}|\le \sqrt{u_{ii}v_{jj}}\le\frac12(u_{ii}+v_{jj})$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
|x_{ii}|&\le\frac12(u_{ii}+v_{ii})\le\frac12(1+1)=1,\\
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_{ii}|&\le\frac12\left(\sum_{i=1}^nu_{ii}+\sum_{i=1}^nv_{ii}\right)\le\frac12(\operatorname{tr}(U)+\operatorname{tr}(V))=k.\\
\end{align*}

Thanks! I was so close, but missed the property of principal minor.
